# Implement multiple thumbnail to multiple slide javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, thumbnails

I'm doing my online portfolio and I'm doing one page with multiple slideshows and thumbnail for each project

Now I encountered several problems when having multiple slideshows in one page, different classes for each slides etc. I found a webpage where I could inspect the javascrip and make my slideshow work, but not the thumbnails, after researching and trying to understand "How? and "Why?" I gave up to try alone, since I'm completely new to javascript and jQuery it is requiring a lot of time and effort.

Pls check the code below... I hope I was clear and that the code is also clear. I'm also new to stackoverflow so i apologise if I'm not pertinent

best
Alex

P.S: in the example below i repeated the the first  but in the actual portfolio that i'm doing each img and the quantity of img in each slide and thumb is different .

```js
//Slide

var filterActive = false;

function nextSlide($slide) {
    var $container = $slide.parent('.slides'),
        slidesCount = $container.data('slides-count'),
        slideIndex = $slide.data('slide-index');

    console.log(slidesCount, slideIndex);

    if (slideIndex < slidesCount) {
        $slide.next('.slide').toggleClass('slide-active');
        $slide.toggleClass('slide-active');
    } else {
        $container.children().first().toggleClass('slide-active');
        $slide.toggleClass('slide-active');
    }
}

$('.slide').click(function() {
        nextSlide($(this));
    });
```

```css
/* Style for index.html_Alexander Portfolio */
* { box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12pt; 4vmin;
  font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, Helvetica-Neue, sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  hyphens: none;
  text-transform: full-width;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-spacing: -1px; 
  letter-spacing: .775px;
  background: none;
  margin: 8px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;


}

article, div, main, header,p {
  border:none; 1px lightgrey;
}

::selection {
  background: #ADFF2F;
}
/*index page*/

.header {
  display: block;
  height:auto;
  width:23%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  line-height: normal;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  color: inherit;
}
.header a:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid;}


.projectS{
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 1em
}

.project{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a b b";
  grid-template-columns:85px 2fr;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  width:auto;
}

/*Slide show container*/
.slides {
  grid-area:b;  
  max-width:auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}


.project-image {
  max-height: 712px;
  max-width:100%;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.slide{
  display: none;
  cursor: e-resize; 
  margin: 0 0 0.1em 0;
  object-fit: contain;

}

.slide-active {
  display: block;
}

.figureCaption {
 font-size: 9pt;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

/*SideThumbs*/

.thumbs_sidebar {
  grid-area:a;
  display:block;
  height:712px; 
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;

}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.thumbs {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  width: 97%;
}

.landscape{
  width: 97%;

}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.thumbs:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--1Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>

<!--2Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>

<!--1Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>

<!--3Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>

<!--4Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>

<!--5Project-->
<article class="project"
<!--sideThumbs-->
<div class="thumbs_sidebar">
          <div class="portrait"><img class="thumbs" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg" alt="Front Cover"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg" alt="inside spread"></div>
          <div class="landscape"><img class="thumbs" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106" alt="inside spread"></div>                    
    </div>
    <!--slide-show-->
    <div class="slides" data-slides-count="4">
      <figure class="slide slide-active" data-slide-index="1">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/032318/files/039751142/600x600x2/epic-armoury-goblin-mask-green-larp-mask.jpg">
      </figure>           
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="2">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://www.eviltailors.com/17356-big_default/goblin-overlord-green.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="3">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g5KvkXMTL.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide" data-slide-index="4">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://partycity6.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_pdp_sq_?$_1000x1000_$&$product=PartyCity/P178106">
      </figure>
<!--description of the project-->
    <p class="description"><em>TitleHere</em>&emsp;&emsp;2018.&emsp;&emsp; Print on request &emsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
    </div>
</article>



</main>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```